# How to get VSCode to run an apscheduler without terminating?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, apscheduler

When I click the arrow to run the python code, it simply executes.
However, if I select the option to run the code line-by-line, then the scheduled tasks will continually run as desired.

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

sched = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)

frequency = 10/60

def main_func(frequency):
    start_time = datetime.now()
    end_time = start_time + timedelta(minutes=frequency)
    
    print("Start Time: ", start_time)
    print("End Time: ", end_time)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sched.add_job(main_func, 'interval', [frequency], minutes=frequency)
    sched.start()
```

**(Undesired): Pressing Button in VSCode:**

[image: Pressing Run Button in VSCode]

**(Desired): Selecting All Code in script within VSCode, Right Clicking and Run Line-by-Line**

[image]

**Questions:**

How can I run the python file so it behaves like I ran it line-by-line and doesn't immediately terminate?

Also, will that method work if I ran the python script from a task scheduler?

Comment: I found if I add input() to the end, it won't kill the program and stop execution.
Also, if I create an infinite while loop, it won't kill the program and stop execution so the task can still run in the background. That seems like a waste of resources though.

But what does input() have in it's definition to prevent the program from exiting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is is literally the first entry in the [APScheduler FAQ](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/faq.html#why-doesn-t-the-scheduler-run-my-jobs).

The essence is that you're starting a *background* service and then letting the script run to the end which then exits the process. Use cases like these are what `BlockingScheduler` is for:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

sched = BlockingScheduler()

frequency = 10/60

def main_func(frequency):
    start_time = datetime.now()
    end_time = start_time + timedelta(minutes=frequency)
    
    print("Start Time: ", start_time)
    print("End Time: ", end_time)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sched.add_job(main_func, 'interval', [frequency], minutes=frequency)
    sched.start()
```